# Import/export-excel problem with powershell

Tags: excel, string, powershell, filtering

So all I want to do is import an excel file containing a number of purchases, and select all the rows with the words "walmart", "mcdonalds" and "burger king" in it. Then export the result back to an excel file. I have installed the excel module. I have tried an enormous amount of things but I usually only get jibberish in the export file.

My excel file has 4 columns, the "name" column being column B. But the columns have no names, the first row is the first purchase.

Please help, thank you.

EDIT:
Heres an example (Semicolon means next cell):

1. ; 1.feb.2021 ; bought goods from blabla ; -25 $ ; 400 $ (<--total)
2. ; 5.feb.2021 ; purchase on MCDONALDS ; -10 $ ; 390 $
3. ; 7.feb.2021 ; purchase from random company ; -30 $ ; 360 $
4. ; 7.feb.2021 ; purchase from company X ; -15 $ ; 345 $
5. ; 9.feb.2021 ; purchase from BURGERKING ; -7 $ ; 338 $

I want to get rid of every row/line not containing the words i want, for example mcdonalds and burger king,
and export the result to another excel file so i can find the sum of these purchases.

I have no idea what to attempt next, this is my 4th week learning powershell, ive tried something like

```
(import-excel "C:\purchases.xlsx") | select-string ".*chinese*.", 
".*burgerking*.", ".*mcdonalds*." | export-excel "C:\outfile.xlsx"
```

but thats clearly not correct.
I'll try some of the stuff user19702 mentioned, thanks for the help.

Edit 2: This worked for filtering the file in powershell but exporting the file doesnt work, the outfile is blank. Heres the code and output:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> $purchase = Import-Excel 
"C:\Users\sonde\Desktop\personlig-prosjekter\pengebruk\visakort-3mnd.xlsx" - 
NoHeader | % { if($_ -match "visa") {write-host $_}}

@{P1=02.02.2021 00:00:00; P2=VISA VARE XXXXXXXXXX 01.02  0,00 
GOOGLE*YOUTUBE SUPER\INTERNET Kurs; P3=-50; P4=5725,16; P5=; P6=; P7=}

@{P1=02.02.2021 00:00:00; P2=VISA VARE XXXXXXXXXXX 01.02  0,00 GOOGLE 
*YouTube Super\g.co/helppay# Kurs; P3=-100; P4=10360,93; P5=; P6=; P7=}

@{P1=01.02.2021 00:00:00; P2=VISA VARE XXXXXXXXX 30.01  0,00 GOOGLE 
*Google Play Ap\g.co/helppay Kurs; P3=-29; P4=10460,93; P5=; P6=; P7=}
```

Comment: Please show your code and in the best case some sanitized lines of example data for us to be able to reproduce your situation. Keep in mind we cannot see your screen and we cannot read your mind.  ;-)   (If you post code or sample data format them as code please.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming:

- `mcdonalds`, `burger king`, etc are in the first column
- that there is only one worksheet
- that there are no tables
- that the entire worksheet is your purchases
- your (empty) column names are in Row #1

Then this should work normally:

```
Import-Module importExcel
Import-Excel "C:\path\to\purchases.xlsx" -NoHeader -StartRow 2 | 
  where P1 -in ('mcdonalds','burger king','walmart') | 
  Export-Excel "C:\path\to\purchases-filtered.xlsx" -StartRow 2 -NoHeader
```

- `-NoHeader` tells `Import-Excel` to create its own column names: P1,P2,P3 etc.
- `-StartRow` is saying how many rows from the top to skip while reading or writing.

Note: if you add column names for the other columns, it will be much simpler to manipulate data